# IE Application: webform not recognized by Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to fill a webform that is created with a button click that does not load a new page. When I try to interact with the Elements of the form, Excel throws a : 424 Error Object required.

It seems that Excel doesn't acknowledge the new field created after the button click, but I can't figure out how to get the new element without re-loading the page.

```
With ie
        .Navigate "https://accounts/New/"

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            With .Document
                .getElementById("DeliverDateTextBox").Value = docDate
                .getElementById("DateTextBox").Value = docDate
                .getElementById("DueDateTextBox").Value = docDate
                .getElementById("TheirRefTextBox").Value = docDescription
                .getElementById("CurrCodeTextBox").selectedIndex = 1
                .getElementById("NewLine2").Click
            End With

        While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend 'Waiting for the page to be ready after the click?

            With .Document
                .getElementById("Text1").Value = "Hello" 'Code throws an error: 424 Object required (textarea)
                .getElementById("VATCode").Value = "A1"'Code throws an error: 424 Object required (input area)
                .getElementById("grosstonet").Click
            End With

        End With
```

this is the HTML code i'm trying to interact with:
For the first element where I try to put "Hello"

```
<textarea name="Detail" rows="3" cols="20" id="Text1" 
tabindex="530" class="Small" 
style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-style:Inset;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;height:84px;width:320px;">
</textarea>
```

For the second element where I try to put "A1"

```
<input name="VAT" type="text" value="A3" id="VATCode" 
tabindex="600" style="color:Black;background-color:White;border-style:Inset;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;width:30px;" 
autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Could be a timing problem. Try putting breakpoint on the second `While` loop and waiting a few seconds before continuing - does it work if you do that?

Comment: @TimWilliams I currently do not have access to my file, I'll try tomorrow first thing in the morning! I think you are correct about the timing issue, but I assumed that the second while would wait until you can interact with the element...

Comment: That type of loop doesn't account for content being added dynamically after the page is done fetching resources from the server: when the loop exits there could still be client-side scripts still working on adding inputs/elements

Comment: @TimWilliams It's indeed a timing issue!  I set up a sleep function and tried to look up how to retrieve the time execution of the button but couldn't figure out how... Is there a way to track those dynamic changes?

Comment: You can only keep testing for the element you want, and wait until it appears (with some suitable timeout so it doesn't wait forever)